# nodejs variable not passing to an inner function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I have written the code below but am not able to get the inner function `.each` to be able to call `res.write` with the results from the MongoDB query.

I initially believed that the problem could be due to the fact that the variable `res` was not global, but even after trying it as a global variable it still did not work, and it being global or not should not affect the code because the .each function is inside of the `showSidebarData` function that is being passed the *res* string.

```
function showSidebarData(res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  coll.find({}, function(err, cursor) {
    item = new Array();
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      if(doc!==null){
        item.push(doc);
      }else{
        var data = {
          "item": item
        };
        fs.readFile('/usr/share/node/pathtofile.html', 'utf8', function(err, html){
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          res.write(dispatcher.templateEngine(html, data));
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

My goal is to be able to write the results from the template engine function inside the file read to the data stream inside of `res`. As a side note, the else statement for `if(doc!==null)` is always run after all the collection query results have been iterated over.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's not working?

Comment: @JohnnyHK the `res` function is not being called inside of the `readfile` I think that it may be because of the scope of the `res` variable.

Comment: The scope of `res` is fine.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Then do you have any ideas on why `res.write` isnt creating an out put and or any ideas on how to debug it, because im not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function that was calling `showSidebar()` was using the correct scope but because of the nature or javascript the respose was being closed before the file stream was done reading the file and wanted to write to `res`. the solution was to comment out `res.end()` in the code below.

```
dispatcher.onGet("/admin/leftSidebar", function(req, res) {
        if(req.params.cookies.session=="session-key"){
showSidebarData(res);

}else{
 res.write("sorry but your username and/or password was invalid please go try brute forcing someone elses site");   
}
// commenting out the line below makes this code work 
    res.end();
});
```

I would like to thank @johnnyHK for the help.